# awk: to find out of order data in a single file

Tags: awk

For the example file contents below

```
00000001.00000001
00000001.00000002
00000001.00000003
00000001.00000004
00000001.00000006
00000001.00000010
00000002.00000001
00000002.00000002
00000002.00000003
00000002.00000004
0000000b.00000001
```

Need to find the out of order data. Out of order meaning here is after 00000001.00000004 next should come is 00000001.00000005 not 00000001.00000006 as in the above. 00000001.00000010 is also a wrong entry as after 00000001.00000006 next 00000001.00000007 should come.

Using awk can we print odd likes 00000001.00000006 and 00000001.00000010 from the above file.

Note that all are considered here as numbers which will be in hexadecimals. EG 0000001a.0000000b are hexadecimal numbers means 8digithexadecimal.8digithexadecimal.

Comment: how about `00000002.00000001`, out of order too? pre one is `00000001.00000010` or only the last digit(s) are significant ?

Comment: no 00000002.00000001 is not considered here as out of order as its first value is 00000002 not 00000001.

Comment: also 10 duplicated lines like `001.001`, all 10 lines are in order?

Comment: awk  -F"." '{ a=$1;b=$2; getline; c=$1;d=$2; if (c==a && d!=(b++)) print;}' file
above is not working

Comment: there are so far two answers below, try them.

Comment: Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F. 'NR > 1 && $1==a && $2 + 0 != b + 1; { a=$1; b=$2 + 0 }' file
```

Results:

```
00000001.00000006
00000001.00000010
```

---

***EDIT1:***

```
awk -F. 'NR > 1 && strtonum("0x" $1) == a && strtonum("0x" $2) != b + 1; { a=strtonum("0x" $1); b=strtonum("0x" $2) }' file
```

Results:

```
00000001.00000006
00000001.00000010
```

---

***EDIT2:***

String comparison:

```
awk -F. '$1 != x; { x = $1 }' file
```

Hex comparison:

```
awk -F. 'strtonum("0x" $1) != x; { x = strtonum("0x" $1) }' file
```

Results:

```
00000001.00000001
00000002.00000001
0000000b.00000001
```

Comment: Oops above not working. Note that all are considered here as numbers which will be in hexadecimals. EG a.b so a and b are hexadecimal numbers

Comment: @Omprakash: You'll need `GNU awk` to handle your hex. See the `strtonum()` function [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions). I'll update my answer in a minute. HTH.

Comment: Thanks it works. But in m/c where I have older awk version getting the error.

awk: calling undefined function strtonum
 input record number 1, file sortfile
 source line number 1

Can it be possible without using strtonum we can do it?

Comment: @Omprakash: Yes, you will need `gawk` on that box. Otherwise you'll need to write your own function to emulate `strtonum()` if you want to use `awk`. But it's probably easier to just install `gawk`. Goodluck.

Comment: How to print starting sequences from the above file.
Output should be:
      00000001.00000001
      00000002.00000001
      0000000b.00000001

means in above pattern a.1, a.2, a.3 , b.1 when ever 'a' changes to  new one let say 'b' then that line should be printed

Comment: Thanks.
I tried the below and it works.

awk -F. 'NR > 0 && strtonum("0x" $1) != a; { a=strtonum("0x" $1); b=strtonum("0x" $2) }' file

Comment: @Omprakash: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do now - but I can tell you that there's no need to define `b=strtonum("0x" $2)` because you make no other reference to it. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question right.

You could try this one liner:

```
awk -F. 'NR>1 && $1-a==0 && $2-b!=1{print}{a=$1;b=$2}' file
```

given your example data, this short line outputs:

```
00000001.00000006
00000001.00000010
```

You could test with your real data, and report the result. I hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: This would render false negatives in case there are more first fields that end with a different letter after a previous line with another letter instead of a number (because `$1-a==0` would then hold true.. )

Comment: Note that all are considered here as numbers which will be in hexadecimals. EG a.b so a and b are hexadecimal numbers

Comment: and both will always be of 8 digts.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print (NR>1&&!(($1-a)=="1e-08"||($1-a)=="1"))?$1" < OutOfOrder":$1;a=$1}'
00000001.00000001
00000001.00000002
00000001.00000003
00000001.00000004
00000001.00000006 < OutOfOrder
00000001.00000010 < OutOfOrder
00000002.00000001
00000002.00000002
00000002.00000003
00000002.00000004
0000000b.00000001 < OutOfOrder
```

Comment: This is not out of order this is the start of next seq

Comment: `00000002.00000005` to `00000002.00000010` are missing so `0000000b.00000001` is out of order?

Comment: Sorry I think I am not clearly said the question. 
Let say a.1 then a.2 then a.5 that means a.5 is out of order. here comparision is relative to previous values and a. OR say a.b the b should be ordered relative to a.

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
awk -F. 'p!=$1{p=$1; v=$2; next} v+1!=v=$2' file
```